# Triage Review Queue - Inconsistent guidelines for "Requires Editing"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, triage

According to a highly-upvoted answer [here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674), by someone who's clearly put considerable time and thought into putting together useful guidelines, we should not be clicking "Requires Editing" when further information is required from the author. Quote (emphasis original):

> (Note that none of these include waiting for any further interaction with or effort from the question author. That's because **if anything more is needed from them**, even though it *does* require editing, ***it doesn't <kbd>Require Editing</kbd> and you shouldn't choose this option***. It is difficult to over-emphasize this, and this is almost certainly the single most common error in Triage.)

However, the Triage Queue instructions themselves seem to directly contradict this, saying "Requires Editing for questions where edits **by the author** or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable" (emphasis added).

What is the correct answer?

Comment: Related [1](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287024/difference-between-should-be-improved-and-unsalvageable-in-triage), [2](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289738/suggestion-for-rewording-of-triage-review-guidance).

Comment: I voted to reopen this question because it is thoroughly ***not*** a duplicate of the linked question. There probably is a duplicate out there, but that isn't it.

Comment: @TinyGiant That question does actually suggest changing the working that this question is concerned with, into something that would answer this question, but that makes up like 5% of what that question is talking about.  But yeah, there are almost certainly much better dupes out there that just focus on this one problem, probably several.

Comment: @Servy precisely my point

Comment: @TinyGiant That question answers this one, so it's not "thoroughly not a duplicate", as reading it would answer his question, it's just a *bad* duplicate, because there's a lot of noise he'd need to read through to find it.

Comment: @Servy it doesn't *really* answer this question as it suggests a change, whereas this question is asking for what the current guidance is, *not* suggesting a change, or even asking for anything to be changed. They are to very different questions on a similar topic, they are not duplicates.

Comment: @TinyGiant That question is suggesting that the wording be changed to reflect the fact that people aren't supposed to be marking unclear questions as requires editing, which answers this question of what should you do with posts that are unclear.  They're asking different questions, but that question answers this one.

Comment: @servy I sincerely disagree, I propose that we just agree to disagree and move on.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If it's not *possible* for the community to edit it into an appropriate question, don't select "requires editing".  All you're doing is sending the post over to other community members and asking them to edit it, when they'll have nothing to do but vote to close the question, as you should have done from the start if the question isn't answerable, or fixable, by the community.

Comment: Thanks, so this must mean that the Triage Queue instructions are wrong, or at best misleading then?

Comment: @BradThomas Yes.

Comment: @Servy when does anything get done about it?

Comment: @JanDvorak I would have hoped that it would have been fixed like a year and a half ago, when I first pointed out the problem.  I wouldn't have expected it to take that long, but here we are.

Comment: Someone suggesting that triage is broken and should be fixed? That's never happened before...

Comment: My steward badge should be forfeited. I've been clicking _Requires editing_ a few dozen times when the question lacked information :(.

Comment: Don't worry, the 6-8 estimation is never wrong.

Comment: "they'll have nothing to do but vote to close the question".  IIRC, the only option is to flag as "Very Low Quality".  Which is different than "Vote to Close", but we don't get that option.

Comment: @teepeemm there's nothing stopping you from navigating to the question and performing any of the actions available to you there

Comment: So how come it's taking more than a year to remove three words from a website page?

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat Why are you asking me?

Answer (score 7):

As of today, the guidance now reads:

[image: Requires Editing for questions that you can make clear and answerable by editing]

...and also includes a second link to [this meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674) as the last line in the expanded instructions (same answer linked to in "help separating questions" in the short explanation at the top).

This is based on [a suggestion by K.Davis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363221/triage-requires-editing-notification-to-new-reviewers/363230#363230) a few months back, and I think it nicely side-steps the problems inherent in asking reviewers to guess at what others are able to fix.

Of course, we'll see how much of an effect it actually has in practice.

Comment: Why not change the balloon help that appears when you hover over the button to match the text above?