# Why did I get suspended from reviewing for 7 days instead of 2 without any explanation?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage, review-suspension

A lot of people look to be confused about review reviewing, and I think I'm one of them.

I just got banned for 7 days after what appears to be a correct series of reviews to me, look at my history if you want and if you find something, please explain it to me. I'm neither looking for conflict nor complaining, I'd like to understand where I got **so** wrong that I could be banned like that and that the 2 days ban could be skipped.

I've been looking around and I don't really find a reason for a straight 7 days suspension instead of 2. Also, I never failed an audit. Even the examples given automatically by the system don't sound like a good reason to me to just ban without warning or explanation:

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you
>   should have reviewed differently, see:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12135260 Come back in 7 days to
>   continue reviewing.

Comment: You got a review ban for 7 days because you've been suspended for 2 days, before. (That's how the system works, each subsequent ban is longer). You don't get banned for a _single_ audit, even though you're given increasingly less leeway with each subsequent review ban. Apparently, you made one too many mistakes since the last review ban.

Comment: Well the problem is that I didn't get banned for 2 days. If so, I wasn't notified for this at all. I would have payed attention the first time if so. But even considering I have been in the past, where did I go wrong this time?

Comment: @Cerbrus That's the normal case for automatic bans - in this case it was manually imposed by a moderator.

Comment: @JonClements Well I'd greatly appreciate to hear the reason for that ban.

Comment: @JonClements The example given is: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12135260. But I'm in accordance with the consensus and moreover, the question can be edited to be improved and thus, doesn't require flag / moderator attention.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat I'll leave the mod involved to explain but in short "requires editing" were chosen to what were "unsalvageable" posts...

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat I have a feeling that example is meant to be: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12134881

Comment: @JonClements yeah but that's the problem, you have a "feeling", I do too (many of them actually). But how am I supposed to improve if I don't have a proper explanation of when I was wrong and why?

Comment: I'm okay with getting banned, I'm not okay with getting banned without explanation or warning and not starting with the default penalty.

Comment: For requires editing, someone other than the OP should be able to improve it such that it's a reasonable question. That's not the case here because there's too much missing. You're just pushing garbage into the improvement queue.

Comment: You might find the Triage Guidance handy: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, that's the explanation I should have received before. I thought "requires editing" was more general including editing from OP. Shouldn't it be named differently to avoid this confusion?

Comment: @rene how come this guide is hidden within the meta pages?.. Thanks for that

Comment: With everything said, I feel like this ban had a total lack of any explanation. I had what I was looking for so I'm deleting the post since downvotes suggest it's not helpful...

Comment: It is tagged [faq] so it is not that much hidden but maybe a helper pane at the right similar to what exists in H&I might be useful.

Comment: I think this question should stay here for future users that are banned *without warning for no apparent reason*

Comment: Ok, but apparently that's not what most users feel about my `-8` question. I'm considering opening a discussion about adding clarity on reviewing, look for the next ~`-10` question.

Comment: @rene I saw a post that said something like "I got banned 2 days, then 7, then 30, then 2 again, etc." and people from SO just replied something like "reviewing is not for you". I think it demonstrates the closed off mentality around the topic and how the functionality lacks explanations and clarity. Reviewing is meant to anybody (that not only has badges in mind) willing to do good, considering he had proper explanations.

Comment: Just know that voting on meta is different, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta it doesn't have effect on your rep on main and it is primarily used to voice disagreement with your statement. Also worth mentioning is that users who blame the system instead of looking at their own contribution to the situation they are in are not received well. So instead of saying *The system is wrong* write your post to ask *How can I improve to prevent this from happening again*. A non-explosive title would help there.

Comment: @Adrien, concerning the perceived lack of explanation, I'll try an analogy. You say you like chess, so consider a review ban as a couple of question marks beside one of your moves -- you screwed up, would it really be useful to detail exactly how you screwed up?

Comment: Yeah that's why I was considering closing that one to open a more constructive discussion about improving suspensions clarity. As I said, I'm only after answers and explanations on what happened, I wanted the title to look like something "wtf". Sorry if it looks explosive, but I feel like a lot of users thought "yet another reviewer that got banned that is here complaining" and just downvoted without paying much attention.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi absolutely. I had no explanation whatsoever on where I screwed up. In chess, when I screw up, I first look at where I screwed up and why. If somebody else tells me that I screwed up, I'm usually looking for some kind of explanation... You can't just say: "hey you did sh*t, go away" without detailing anything.

Comment: Even if you are a full-of-gold-badges-user with total ninja control on machines...

Comment: *how come this guide is hidden within the meta pages?* @AdrienBrunelat - Feature request to put a link to it in triage?

Comment: @BSMP yeah, when I'll have a little bit of time I'll post a nice and clean post to discuss lack of clarity withing triage pages.

Comment: related: [Triage Review Queue - Inconsistent guidelines for “Requires Editing”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319128/triage-review-queue-inconsistent-guidelines-for-requires-editing)

Comment: If you want to discuss what changes should be made to avoid this in the future you should ask another question since this one has an answer and you're changing it so that my answer does not completely answer the question any more.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For requires editing, someone other than the OP should be able to improve it such that it's a reasonable question. That's not the case here because there's too much missing.

You're just pushing garbage into the improvement queue which will frustrate the people who are active in that queue.

Your 7 day ban was manually applied by a moderator, that's why you didn't get a 2 day ban first.

There's more information on what options to choose [in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue) [Thanks to rene for finding that]

The text from that answer says this about Requires Editing:

> (Note that none of these include waiting for any further interaction with or effort from the question author. That's because if anything more is needed from them, even though it does require editing, it doesn't Require Editing and you shouldn't choose this option. It is difficult to over-emphasize this, and this is almost certainly the single most common error in Triage.)

Comment: This is exactly it. I stumbled across some really wrong triage reviews this morning and took a closer look at a sample around that time as a result. I'd estimate that around 30-50% of "requires editing" votes should be "unsalvageable" instead, which needs to change to make H&I queue better.

Comment: Just so that you guys realise, the guidelines for `requires editing` in SO are: "Requires Editing for questions where edits **by the author** or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable"

Comment: And people are still complaining about reviewers getting it wrong saying bull***t like "reviewing is not for you"...

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat that means others can do it if the author can't or won't. It certainly does not say **by the author alone would result in a question...**

Comment: @RobertLongson don't deny it's a confusing way of putting it. By the author or others could mean that one of the two must be able to edit it, for others it can mean that both should be able to do so. It's absolutely possible to assume a system that would notify OP if his question had been marked too many times as "requires editing". Of course, it sounds obvious that it is not the case when you understand how triage works, but those guidelines are not meant for people who understand how triage works, they'd be useless.