# What did I do wrong with the review ban example task?

Tags: support, review-suspension

I was banned from reviewing, and as an example there was a [task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12135181) I reviewed as `Requires Editing`. I still think it was the correct choice. What did I do wrong with that task?

Comment: Probably related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321664/1743880

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For that specific review, *"Requires editing"* is incorrect.

There's no amount of editing a user could do to improve the quality of the question enough, so that it's of sufficient quality for SO.

The OP didn't provide any information aside from the error message and a single line of code. Only the OP can fix that post by providing an [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When the review happened it looked like this: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36834369/1

Comment: ^ Requires deletion o.O