# Change triage guidelines for "requires editing"

Tags: bug, status-completed, triage

According to these posts: [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319128/triage-review-queue-inconsistent-guidelines-for-requires-editing) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321664/why-did-i-get-suspended-from-reviewing-for-7-days-instead-of-2-without-any-expla?noredirect=1#comment337792_321664) (and some other posts around Meta), the following guidelines for <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd> in the triage section are misleading:

> **Requires Editing** for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable

Since this is, IMHO, the source for the most common mistake during post reviews, I'm suggesting changing them to:

> **Requires Editing** for questions where edits by other members of the community would result in a question that is clear and answerable

Comment: Would have loved to add a beautiful screenshot to illustrate, but unfortunately, I cannot review for some time.

Comment: I've lifted your review ban. Thanks for your perseverance in trying to make the site better and this suggestion (which I happen to agree with).

Comment: Can this question get re-opened and be reconsidered as its own request? Just because the other changes in the dupe may not improve things doesn't mean we shouldn't correct text that is flat out wrong.

Comment: This is a bug, in and of itself; it should be reopened, fixed, and closed as [tag:status-complete]. See [the confusion it causes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319128/triage-review-queue-inconsistent-guidelines-for-requires-editing). Waiting while a big rewrite is proposed and worked out is silly. Fix the broken bit now.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Thank you for perservering. This has, again, [caused an issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338596/review-suspension-contradictory-recommendation) and even resulted in three people simultaneously being suspended/banned.

Comment: @JonClements Another big problem with `Requires Editing` is when you begin doing review queues you only have 10 flags a day but you have 20 questions in your queue. So when you're out of flags and you're presented a bad question you have 3 options: (1) `Looks OK` which you will not press because it's not OK, (2) `Skip` - which will not count towards progression of finishing the queue, and (3) `Requires Editing` - which you'll press most likely.

Comment: This is really a bit frustrating. I'm currently spending quite some time on the Triage queue. It happens to me all the time that out 4 or 5 reviewers, I'm the only one flagging a question as `Unsalvageable` while everyone else flags as `Requires Editing`, even though there is clearly missing information that only the OP could provide. I think *many* Triage queue reviewers think that `Requires Editing` means editing by the OP, even though it doesn't make a lot of sense if you think about it.

Comment: I misunderstand `Requires Editing` too. I think it means the question can be improved by OP and other community users until I got `There are no review queues available to you`. The message means I am banned for review queue.  Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24682588, I triaged this question as `Requires Editing`. I think I am correct, the question can be exactly improved.  But some users triaged it as `unsalvagable`. Why I am banned? Because the number of users choose `unsalvagable` is large? I don't agree with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of today, the guidance now reads:

[image: Requires Editing for questions that you can make clear and answerable by editing]

...and also includes a second link to [this meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674) as the last line in the expanded instructions (same answer linked to in "help separating questions" in the short explanation at the top).

This is based on [a suggestion by K.Davis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363221) a few months back, and I think it nicely side-steps the problems inherent in asking reviewers to guess at what others are able to fix.

Of course, we'll see how much of an effect it actually has in practice.

Answer (score 19):

In addition to updating/fixing the guidance text that shows when you click on *more* I suggest that we also update the text you see when hovering over the requires editing button.

**Both** should include something along the lines of "users **other than the OP** can fix this question" (including the emphasis), just so there won't be any room for misinterpretation any more. I could imagine that most reviewers currently do actually read the text that shows when hovering the buttons even if they don't bother to read the guidance.

Just for reference, it currently says:

> this question could be good, but requires some time and attention of
>   editors

I think both texts should be the same (or at least almost the same) to reduce possible confusion even more.

I'm not starting a new feature-request or question since this is an issue that is highly connected to the wrong guidance text (which is an *actual bug* that hasn't been fixed yet despite this question being a year old) and because it could be easily and quickly fixed together with the guidance text in one go if a developer was kind enough to give it a couple of minutes of attention.

[Also, here's a related suggestion that falls under the same general topic.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346194/6214222)

Answer (score 9):

I totally agree with this.

At first, when I got access to the triage queue, I was a bit unsure about how to use "Required Editing". I think many people (including me, sorry) used it as a way to reject it without having to choose an appropriate reason, as you have to when you click on "Unsalvageable". I cannot enough emphasize how much I realized how wrong this behavior was when I reached 2000 rep and got access to the "Help and improvement" queue. It is completely flooded with questions that should be removed.

Maybe both "Requires Editing" and the whole "Help and improvements" should be removed completely. Or maybe "Very low quality" should be an option when you click on "Unsalvageable".

But yes, if that's not an option I completely agree that it should be 100% clear that "Requires Editing" in 99% of the cases means that someone else than the author has to take care of it.

Comment: Yes, this is so true. Exactly the kind of simple confusion that a change in wording (especially on the button itself) could help mitigate. Because who doesn't want to reject poor questions with a single-click?

Answer (score 3):

#### Proposal for the following minor changes to the help tips in the Triage queue:

- Action button text should change from "Requires Editing" to **"OK, but requires Minor Edits"**
- Tool tip for the action button *(a.k.a Title text)* should change from

  - "this question could be good, but requires some time and attention of editors" *to*
  - **"this question could be good, but requires some time and attention from community editors"**
- Help text *(e.g. under the [more] link)* should change from

  - "for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable" *to*
  - **"for questions where edits by community editors would result in a question that is clear and answerable"**

No changes are necessary for any of the other Triage buttons or help text.

*(Thanks to the helpful [robinCTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1961728/robincts) for encouraging me to pursue some of these thoughts.)*

Comment: I really like the usage of the "community" word in the phrasing of those help tips. I think this is the best phrasing that now, after almost two years, should be applied.