# why review queue shows "There are no review queues available to you"

Tags: discussion

When i click the review button it show's as below:

[image]

I am seeing this for the first time though previously when there was nothing to review there was the queue name and the number of review need was zero.Is this a new feature of SO or others? Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: You received a review ban (manually applied by a moderator).

Comment: @MartijnPieters One review in the triage section was not helpful, that's why they asked me to come after 3 days.3 others reviewed as Unsalvageable, I reviewed as requires editing.The question was hold for "unclear what you are asking".Because the post was not clear i reviewed to edit.What's the difference?

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/15827496) perhaps? Only the OP can improve that, so it should be closed. "Requires Editing" means that the question can be edited by _others_ than the OP. And yes, [the guidance on the review page is wrong about that....](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321895/change-triage-guidelines-for-requires-editing).

Comment: Some more guidance: [Is there a guide for the Triage queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650/2675154)