# Does Stack Overflow have (or need) rep milestone schools?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, privileges

I've noticed quite a few questions on Meta where users have reached a rep milestone that involves unlocking review queues and thus encountering review audits, and they seem to be struggling with a lack of detailed information. There are a lot of questions about "Why did I fail this audit post?".

I realize that from one point-of-view, the argument could be made that once a user reaches a certain rep level, they should already have what they need to know, but that argument seems to me to make a lot of assumptions about the given user.

If a user reaches the point where they can access a given review queue, does Stack Overflow have a walkthrough or tutorial for those new responsibilities that individual users may choose to take on (Similar to the U.S. armed forces "Command School"), or is the audit process itself intended to serve this need?

Comment: There is some guidance for [Late Answer and First Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505). I would be aware of any other instructions. Your idea sounds interesting. Having a detailed guideline/instruction how to handle each of the queues would be good.

Comment: Earning rep doesn't give anyone *any* additional responsibilities.  It provides users with privileges that they are allowed, but not *responsible* for using.  If you choose to use a given privilege you're responsible for using it correctly, but most users do not utilize at least some of the privileges available to them, and that's perfectly fine.

Comment: @Servy: "If you choose to use a given privilege you're responsible for using it correctly" -- that's exactly my point.

Comment: And yet in your question you say that users take on responsibilities *for reaching a given rep milestone*, which is simply not true.  Users *don't* take on any more responsibility as a result of earning rep.  They take on more responsibility *by choosing to use privileges* that they were given at a certain rep milestone.  They need to *choose* to take on that responsibility.

Comment: @Servy Sorry for being direct here but, _what is your point_? Whether a user chooses to use their privileges or not does not negate the fact that _some users want to use their privileges responsibly_ which is who this question is for, people who _want_ to use their privileges and are struggling with a lack of detailed information. Would the question be more valid in your eyes if it said _to acquaint them with the additional responsibilities that go with a particular milestone **if they choose to use their privileges**_? To me, it's unneeded extra information.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton My point is that trying to tell people how to use a feature that they aren't, and don't intend to, use, is not helpful, and stating that people are responsible for thing *that they aren't responsible for* is problematic, as is any feature based on that premise.  A question asking about providing useful information for people specifically seeking it out is indeed a much better question than one about forcing information on people who have no interest in it.

Comment: @Servy Nowhere does it say that anyone would have anything forced on them, but to have the information to simply be available (in my mind similar to the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) or the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pages as examples), unless I am missing something.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: You're not missing anything.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton It specifically says that when people reach a given reputation milestone they've taken on new responsibilities (which is false, as they have *not* taken on any new responsibilities), and that they should then be directed to tutorials at that time, to learn how to handle their new responsibilities (despite the fact that they have taken on no responsibilities at that time, and therefore shouldn't be presented with tutorials on the topic at that time).

Comment: @MarkBenningfield If your question doesn't intend to say that people are given responsibilities when they reach a given rep threshold, and that we shouldn't be presenting them with tutorials/walkthroughs/etc. when they reach rep milestones, then you should edit your question accordingly, because currently it says exactly that.  Saying, in a comment, that your question doesn't say thing that it specifically says doesn't mean much.

Comment: I could have used some education when I got my first dupe hammer.

Comment: It seems the comments here descended into an argument over the definition of the word "responsibility". According to the almighty Google, one of the definitions is *the **opportunity** or ability to act independently and take decisions without authorization*. So, without a doubt, that is exactly what is given with reputation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We're looking into making this sort of help available through a more 'just in time' mechanism in the future, but a lot of things need to settle down closer to being finally feature-complete (e.g. Review & Channels) before we can focus on it without digging into more technical debt.

An important thing to remember is that it takes a certain kind of user to actually *want* to use the features that they unlock; some people have six-figure rep yet seldom vote, much less review or cast close votes. We need to respect that *as long as we're sure we didn't miss the opportunity to tempt them*.

What's needed are three things, really:

1. Do a better job *marketing* the idea of community self-moderation, and the value proposition for individuals to actually *want* the additional responsibility. Badges are a nice non-intrusive way for folks to discover their new abilities, but we need more (non-intrusive) ways to tempt folks to use the tools that they unlock.
2. Give better *just in time* guidance to folks that start exploring the tools. We do a sort-of-okay-ish job of that now with brief introductory bits of text and help, but we don't do enough of it in a consistent enough manner that folks train on immediately spotting and finding value in learning opportunities. It has to be at least marginally more compelling than people's natural tendency to just dismiss anything that has an X in the upper right corner.
3. We have to make the tools suck less. Way less. This is happening now as we start untangling all *kinds* of technical debt in order to make Channels possible and figure out what sorts of moderation tools they're going to need, but the undertaking is enormous. This has the effect of pulling at separate ends of a twisted rope unraveling it gradually from one side to the other, but it's going to take quite a bit more work. No snazzy just-in-time help is going to seem effective if it's there mostly to work around wonky UX and strange use cases. I actually worry that we lose folks that want to do more just because the tools are too rough around the edges.

Stack Overflow as you see it today is almost a living chronological record of hundreds of small problems that we solved independently of one another after the initial launch that was thought to be nearly feature complete in 2008 (laughs and hilarity ensue). So before we can build *truly* admirable help into the system, we have to go back and add the polish that makes it seem like all of those features were thought of on the first day, and just lightly polished over time.

So if you look at any of the moderation tools in isolation, well, they're pretty darn neat; flagging and reviewing has made SO (and by extension Stack Exchange) one of the safest places on the Internet to ask questions. If you look at all of them *together* .. it looks like a bit of a disjointed mess that many people designed, which is .. well .. exactly what happened :)

As we keep pulling at ends and unraveling messes we're going to get better tools, which *hopefully* won't require as much explanation, and the system will do a good job of letting users know that they didn't necessarily do anything wrong, they just found themselves at odds with what other users thought (a very common reason for people to feel jarred).

I'm more than pretty confident that the messes we unravel thanks to Channels will finally make fixing the tools and finally providing decent help for our *most* engaged users much easier (starting with diamond mods, then reviewers, etc), but we really need to get there and strike that sense of UX consistency before we can build a more comprehensive system to make everything more self-guiding (which always makes me think of this from the original [Total Recall](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100802/)):

[image: Wanna be a moderator?]

.. but yeah, we definitely know we need it, which I probably could have said a bit more clearly in the first paragraph.

Comment: As far as the self-moderation tools go, I gather from the Meta posts that they could use some work, yes. But as I mentioned in another comment, I'm not sure the "clinics" would need to be much more than a notification and link. On the other end of it, I think most of the info is out there, it just isn't centralized, and it's a bit vague in spots. If that information were gathered together with one or two dozen (certainly no more) sample posts with discussion (sort of like an open audit), that would probably be sufficient.

Comment: +1 for better tools.  What is there now sucks.

Comment: The illustration is awful. Please avoid using deadly weapons or people on the verge of death on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Cœur: It's not a deadly weapon, and the character is not on the verge of death. Have you not seen the movie?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield no, I haven't, and it looks like a machine gun in the nose, ready to blow up the head.

Comment: @Cœur: Well, I don't want to put a spoiler on the movie for you, so I'll just say that, while it may be one of the more "cringe-worthy" movie scenes of all time, it's not in any way lethal or deadly.

Comment: Well he could have caught a cold due to the wet towel. He seemed to be fine the next days, but perhaps he just ignored the signs, due to the other distracting things happening around him. Then, after the movie ended, it threw him down…

Answer (score 15):

The first time you review in a certain queue, it will display some guidance:

[image]

which you can hide (with the (less) link) once you're confident you know what to do.

The community has written some [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) posts; for the First Posts and Late Answers review queues, there's [this guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/4751173) and there's also one available for the [Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650/4751173) review queue. There's also a [more general and less detailed one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: The two specific links you mentioned are mostly what I'm talking about; perhaps a bit more comprehensive. Maybe all that's needed is a notification / link to existing guides, so the user wouldn't have to search for them.

Comment: While this the "more information" is available in all review queues at all times, a significant source of problems is that the "information" isn't clear or accurate in [some cases](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321895/change-triage-guidelines-for-requires-editing).

Comment: @Makyen: From what I've been able to piece together so far, it appears that there are a few (more or less) "guide/info" posts for the various review queues, with a fair bit of haziness around the edges. I think most of the information is out there, it's just not localized; and the haziness seems to be the rub.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Yes, he information is out there. The fact that it's not easily accessible to those users who *want* to use their privileges responsibly (i.e. in a manner consistent with community consensus) is a *significant* problem. While we don't need to inundate users with huge amounts of data that they must read prior to using a privileged, it would be very good to have the existing information linked on the pages which do describe it, so that users who *want* to be informed don't have to put out large amounts of effort to find the information.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Unfortunately, SE has demonstrated that they are uninterested in improving this (see above linked meta for request to make a simple change in text, which hasn't been acted on in almost 2 years).

Answer (score 5):

[The Good The Bad The Ugly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly)... is an old feature request of mine that was aimed at educating new users about good and bad posts.

It doesn't directly answer your question, but a mechanism like this could work to educate users in other areas of the site too, like suggested edits.

From the feature request:

> **The Good, The Bad & The Ugly Tutorial**
>
> The purpose of the tutorial would be to highlight what the community deems to be good and bad when it comes to posting.
>
> [image]
>
> On the right hand side would be links similar to the [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) help content, that could popup a dialog with a few short lines / bullet points that provide information.
>
> **Reviews & Feedback**
>
> In the tutorial, after each review item has had a decision cast on it, a dialog should appear alongside the question to highlight exactly why it was good, bad or ugly, so the users can see what is expected and hopefully learn from it.
>
> [image]

Comment: As I understand it, this seems to be pretty similar to the Review Audit process.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield it was meant to be. It's aim is to show users actual site content and get them to judge it, with help available if they were unsure. Once they make a decision, they would then get an outcome telling them if their choice was correct or incorrect along with the reasoning behind it. I'll edit the post to add a bit more info.