# Review ban although no audit fail

Tags: discussion, support, review-suspension

In the last week I've done a lot of reviews. I have passed many audits and haven't failed single one. I just wanted to come back to reviewing and it occurred I got banned for a week.

I guess it's a ban from Flexo who has reviewed the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/13639155) after me. I agree that flagging as unclear what's you're asking would be a better decision, but I had a thought that as the question was just posted and had just 2 views at the moment he'll add the code and it'll get clear. OK, after two hours from posting I agree that it is unclear indeed.

I have made some research on my reviews and this is what I have:

[image]

All my reviews that are on posts on which the review has been finished so far are good. There are some reviews on which I differ from the majority:

1. I say Looks OK, 2 users say Requires Editing.
2. I say Looks OK, 2 users say Requires Editing.

In the rest of reviews I'm with the majority or drawing on 'controversial' posts. Is it ok to ban for a week for just one bad review which would be overridden by other reviewers?

Flexo, did I get banned for this single review or did you inspect any further? For example, did you see that I have 628 helpful flags and 24 declined? I'm trying to make this site a better place in revenge for lots of help I got from the Stack Overflow Community in the past.

---

Does it count as an audit fail so a single audit fail will lead to a monthly ban when the current one ends?

Comment: You did over 125 reviews in just the last 24 hours.  Yikes.  Your screenshot looks a bit incomplete.  Otherwise the kind of mishap that is so common when an SO user is robo-reviewing at mach 3.  These kind of temporary bans are just a hint to slow down and pay more attention.  Quality matters a great deal more than quantity.

Comment: Triage is very often abused by reviewers choosing "Requires Editing" to completely unsalvagable questions, like the one you link to. This also has several impacts, like on the "Help & Improvement" since the post that "requires editing" ends up there. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321664/why-did-i-get-suspended-from-reviewing-for-7-days-instead-of-2-without-any-expla and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332542/ Moderators are now actively banning the reviewers wrongly choosing "Requires Editing".

Comment: Still didn't receive an answer to my last question. @HansPassant the rest was done yesterday. I still made a big statistics on my reviews. I believe bigger then the moderator who banned me from reviewing. I've seen it many times: you don't get banned for a single audit fail and I did. IMO it's unfair.

Comment: @xenteros you can't get banned automatically for a single failed audit.  But if you failed one or more audits in the past, you might not remember them, and they may still count against you.  Similarly, a mod can manually ban you if they felt you did a particularly poor job reviewing a specific edit (which may or may not have been an audit post)

Comment: I haven't failed any audit for the last 35 days, and they disappear after 30 days without a fail

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I applied a ban manually, in this instance because I couldn't quite believe that it would possible to consider this anything but textbook unsalvageable. My thoughts on ["requires editing" vs "unsalvageable"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316295/168175) are already well documented. The only thing I'll emphasise again here is that the OP had all the time in the world to add code (or heck even *any* kind of indication of what they were on about other than 'nav'). In terms of duration of the ban I did look at your recent ban history and this didn't seem any better than the audits you had failed.

At best incorrectly reviewing that post wastes time of people in the Help and Improvement queue. At worst it lets it fall through the cracks and the OP takes longer and more time from others to reach the conclusion of the Q-ban trajectory they (rightly) seemed to be on.

You commented about the low view count and recently posted with an implication that you were offering "grace time" to the OP. If the system wanted you to give questions with low views that were recently posted extra grace time then it simply wouldn't show you the question until that grace time had expired. The fact that you're shown this question in /review is a request for you to make an accurate assessment of it as it exists right here and right now. The outcome of which will determine how to treat the question. (And in the event that it did get closed and the OP did want to fix it their edit would automatically give it a chance to be reviewed for "unholding"/reopening).

There's a grey patch of questions when reviewing, in the middle of the spectrum from great to awful which I agree is hard to review and will always be contentious. I stay far away from those when looking at the review queue and this question was anything but contentious, hence my actions.

Comment: Does this 7 day ban implicate the next one to be month long or are moderator bans parallel to the audit fail bans?

Comment: They are totally disconnected as far as I'm aware. I see a little `javascript:prompt` box on my interface that lets me type in any number up to 30. Mod bans don't count as audit fails though, so the automatic system is unimpacted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't agree with being banned for a single mistake, but hopefully it's the last ban i got. Can't understand why the fact that I have passed many audits and failed none since my previous ban doesn't count. Ok, strict [so] rules. In the end it's useful.

Answer (score 5):

Moderators will sometimes issue manual review bans when they deem it necessary.

Looking at the post you identified that [Flexo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) disagreed with you on; it's very clear that that is a long, long, long shot from "Looks OK". In fact, it's almost a textbook example of a closeable question - you could close it for at least three different reasons.

What happened in this case is most likely that a moderator (it turns out it was Flexo; see his answer below) has seen this one egregious mistake of yours in review, and then went on to check a few more of your reviewed posts, concluding that you need a time out to refine your reviewing skills before continuing.

Comment: I find it more useful to link to the post you are talking about instead of saying "see answer below", because your answer is no longer above the answer you are referencing, while a link would persist endlessly