# Can we have more clear instructions for review queues?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits, triage, review-suspension

I just got access to the review queues and I'm a bit confused. The queues are just *presented* to me, without enough explanation of where the questions came from or where they'll go. In some cases it seems obvious ("First posts"), but is there any way I can know if questions in "Triage" were added automatically or flagged?

And what happens after I review them? For instance, [in this Triage review item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41418514/how-to-read-amadeus-air-file-txt-data-using-php), a user simply posted the contents of a file and asked, in the title, "How do I read this file?" Three reviewers quickly marked the question as "unsalvageable", but the question remained available and open.

Later on, that question was put on hold by 5 users who were not involved in the initial review. I would expect that the review upgraded the question to another queue, but as [commented by 4castle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340687/can-we-have-more-clear-instructions-for-review-queues?noredirect=1#comment427210_340687), it's more likely a "meta effect". I'd like to see some confirmation when I finish the review (it would be very nice if the interface said something in the lines of "thanks for your assistance, this question has been queued in <whatever queue>; it will be reviewed...". Otherwise it really seems that the review was a waste of time.

In general, are reviewed items moved to other queues or is any action automatically executed on them?

And more importantly, what are the **actual** guideline for "requires editing"? The review page says this:

> **Requires Editing** for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable

But apparently the community seems to be reserving this only for situations where anyone *but the author* could improve the question. As I read, [mods seem to be banning reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321666/782570) who follow the page instructions. This looks like a real problem, and I'm feeling quite discouraged to review anything as "Requires Editing".

Comment: Regarding "requires editing" : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue

Comment: See also: [Adopt a consistent policy on what “Requires Editing” means in the review queues](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332546/3614835)

Comment: More on the topic: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254145/suggest-to-me-what-tag-filtering-i-should-use-in-review-next?s=3|0.7037

Comment: The question you linked to was likely closed by people who were reading this meta question and decided to act on what you linked to. This is called the "meta effect".

Comment: This has been an issue with the review queues for **years**. A great deal of the confusion could be cleared up with some simple changes to a few bits of text requiring very little time to implement and *no code* changes (just the displayed text). It is ridiculous that the easy, low hanging changes have not been made. It doesn't have to be 100% perfect. Changes that get us 50%–90% there would be quite beneficial. The benefit is particularly significant for those users who are conscientious enough to be reading the explanation text (i.e. the users we *really want* to be doing reviews).

Comment: The real problem here is the close vote queue is **MASSIVE**.  Once people flag for closure then it enters the close vote queue.  Once there people can vote to close it or leave it alone.  Since there are so many things that needs to get reviewed a lot of things wind up not getting closed even though they should.

Comment: The CV queue is what it is, and it's a problem, but this question pertains to feedback to other reviewers - something just as simple as the information that an unsalvageable review is transferred to the CV queue is important to let Triage reviewers know what they're doing, and also important that the information is available **outside of Meta**.

Comment: @NathanOliver wait, I remember that you need either two flags or 1 close vote to allow a question to enter the close queue, did that changed?

Comment: @Braiam IIRC I was told one flag or one vote is enough to get it into the queue.