# Why should this question be marked as Spam?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, spam

While reviewing some questions in the Triage queue, I came across the following question. (The `-8` was hidden at the time.)

[image: How To Remove Blank Space Below Footer?]

Thinking that it would be a legitimate question if the asker moved the content which was providing them with issues to a code block on StackOverflow rather than only providing a link to their site, I chose the "Requires Editing" option. I was told that I had failed the review audit and must wait until October 5th (one month!) to review any more questions.

Why is this? Is it good practice to mark any UI-related questions containing links to external websites as Spam?

Comment: It's a well known spamming site.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was not aware of this. Also, it seems unfair to fail users for not recognizing a specific spamming website.

Comment: That does not require editing. That is, at the very least, unsalvagable -> No MCVE. [See also](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues). And, well, frankly, borderline spam as the question invites all user to go their website, filled with ads.

Comment: @Tunaki From my standpoint, it seems that moving whatever content was on their site to a code block in the question itself could be acceptable. Is this incorrect?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319128/triage-review-queue-inconsistent-guidelines-for-requires-editing. Essentially the guidance us misleading. If the only person who can fix the post is the OP, then requires editing is the wrong choice

Comment: @psubsee2003 I see. This is very helpful - thank you. :)

Comment: The system would have blocked it outright if it contained *only* a link, so they had to add some filler text. Don't try so hard to make garbage into a question. You are being *far* too generous. This is an unsolicited dump of a website onto another site. That is textbook spam. It doesn't require any expert knowledge or understanding of the history like others have claimed. Don't get mixed up in the confusion about what 'requires editing' means. While that's very real, it is not relevant here. This is just good old spam, straight out of a can. Re-calibrate your filter, please.

Answer (score 7):

One tipoff is that the question doesn't make sense. "How can I remove this blank space below footer?" How could you be expected to know what blank space was being referred to? A quick look at the site is enough to be pretty sure that the only point of the post is to plant a link to the site.

Comment: Fair point. Is it expected of reviewers to click on all links in questions, though? I'm quite curious.

Comment: You shouldn't have to click arbitrary links to determine question topicality. But that also implies "requires editing [by reviewers]" is a bad review, and the question's still unsalvageable ;-)

Comment: @2Cubed I'm not sure if it is expected, but given the suspicious nature of the question, I would either check the site or skip the review.

Answer (score 6):

The intent of posting that link is to promote the site, not to get help with a specific piece of HTML.

Further, any question that posts *just* a link to the site should be put on hold *anyway*, since just a link to a site isn't enough context to answer the question.  We require code posted on the site, not at an external link.

Comment: I understand - this is why I chose "Requires Editing". I was under the assumption that moving the content from that link to a code block would be acceptable.

Comment: @2Cubed that should be done by the OP, though, not the editors. Otherwise the question _still_ ends up too broad / no MCVE

Comment: @JanDvorak Ah, I was unaware of this. Thank you. :)