# Reviewing triage queue, failed audit for unknown (to me) reason

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, triage, review-suspension

I am fairly new to reviewing posts, and I stumbled upon this question to review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/15330791.

The user posted the following text:

> https://c.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Apple-Press-Event-Hey-Siri-give-us-a-hint-6401-980x420.jpg
>   "like this, thanks in advance"

Sure that's not a good question in its form (that's why I chose "Requires editing"), but this review was an audit and I failed. I even doubly failed because I can't see why I should have requested a "Close: spam" action for the following reasons:

- although the user's "question" is not intelligible, we can understand the context with the image,
- the image linked to the post is not spam but, as I understand it, a visual representation of what OP's wanted to achieve.

Where did I go wrong ? Am I missing something ? I am just asking for clarifications to improve my reviewing skills.

Comment: If you want to discuss an audit you should link to the audit, not the question the audit used.

Comment: @Servy changed the link to point to the correct review, thanks :)

Comment: "Requires setting on fire and rolling into dumpster" not "Requires editing"

Comment: As far as the spam thing, it's probably because of the *filename*: Apple-Press-Event-Hey-Siri-give-us-a-hint...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you select "Requires Editing" you're saying

> If someone just edits this question, it will be fine

So what would **you** edit to make it meet the [MCVE standard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I think too many people think that the "Requires Editing" button means that if **the questioner** just edited it, things will be just fine, but that's not what that button does. It sends it into the Help and Improvement queue where **reviewers are supposed to edit it**.

I can't clean that up. I can't even try. There's nothing to edit! The entire question could be reworded as

> How do I do this this thing in the picture? Thanks in advance

We've come to know this in review circles as "Gimme teh codez", where they are expecting some kind soul to come in and provide the code to make it work. But that's not what SO is for. If he had posted some code with his picture it would have been fine.

If you want to know where you went wrong, go spend a few minutes in the Help and Improvement queue. I rarely find questions in there that an edit would fix. Instead I usually use it to cast close votes. After a while of doing those reviews, I think you'll see why clicking "Requires Editing" there was not the right selection.

[From the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue)

> Do not choose "Requires Editing" if you know the question cannot be made answerable without clarification or additions from its author. For example, if an android question asks for an explanation of errors found in logcat, but omits specific errors and/or logcat listing, the question doesn't require editing - it requires more information, so choose Unsalvageable->should be closed->unclear what you're asking.
>
> If you don't know whether the question can be fixed by editing - perhaps you've never worked with the technologies involved and simply can't tell if it's a reasonable question for topic-experts - then Skip; there are other questions that need your attention more.

Comment: Just to note that may not be what the button does the the tool tip clearly states *Requires Editing: for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable*.  SO so far has not changed that despite repeated requests to do so.(IMHO they really need to do so, like now)

Comment: @NathanOliver It's way too late by now.  I'm not sure if that wording change would be enough had they done it several years ago when I first brought it up *before the alpha even went live*.  By now there are too many triage reviewers who have trained themselves on the idea that all questions require editing; none are perfect, and none are unsalvageable.  And they all already know this, and think that they're great reviewers when they send every single question to HI.

Comment: @Servy I'm not so sure it is to late.  If we make the change then we can use the audit system to retrain people.  It definitely can't hurt to change the  guidance.

Comment: @NathanOliver It certainly can't hurt, and I'm not saying they shouldn't fix their broken instructions, because they certainly should, I'm just saying that you can't expect the system to actually start working, and for the HI queue to actually become usable, just because they fix that.  They've worked too hard for too many years to train all of their users to do the wrong thing for a tiny tooltip fix to undo it.

Comment: @Servy I see.  No I didn't expect it to insta-fix it but if we want to fix it it's at least a start.  Then when people complain at least we can say officially that it is only for community edits

Answer (score 7):

> although the user's "question" is not intelligible,

So clearly it merits closure, not editing by the community.

> the image linked to the post is not spam but, as I understand it, a visual representation of what OP's wanted to achieve.

That's still not an intelligible question, and cannot be turned into one by the community.

> Where did I go wrong?

You said that the question was fine, and just needed a bit of help editing its presentation, when in actuality the question is *really* bad, needs to be closed, and can't possibly be turned into an acceptable question through community editing.

Comment: Indeed, I could have selected a "Close: unclear what you're asking" but I thought that if the OP edited his question it might be actually an appropriate one. Regarding the "Requires edit" I guess I got mislead for the same reason this post was created: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321895/change-triage-guidelines-for-requires-editing. Anyway, thanks for the explanation, won't happen again !

Comment: @NaeiKinDus I would give a question this truly awful a 0% chance at actually being salvaged by the author, it's almost literally as bad of a question as one could possibly find, but of course that's irrelevant anyway.  If only the author could improve it, then you need to close it.  Telling other community members to go fix the question when they have no possible means of doing so is the wrong decision, because they can't.

Comment: yeah I figured it out reading http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319129/3876260 (sorry I forced you to repeat yourself ;) )