# Weird audit "requires editing"

Tags: support, review-audits, triage

I just now reviewed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/16162235) and pressed "Requires Editing" by mistake - I didn't see any reason why this had to be changed, it seemed like a valid question, was well formatted and everything. I just misclicked, and thought "oh damn" but: the audit passed.

Can anyone tell me, if this is just a misclassified audit or if there is really something wrong with this question? Because I don't see any reason at all why this should require improvement. Seeing it has 11 upvotes also indicates I should have clicked "Looks OK" (which I intended to do).

Comment: Well, even good posts might need to be edited.  They might be throwing you a bone on the know good audits and not failing you for that.

Comment: This might sound snarky, but I think that's actually what they want you to do in Triage. At the very least they've not bothered to [clarify what it does](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344505/reviewing-triage-queue-failed-audit-for-unknown-to-me-reason/344510#344510)

Comment: I guess it didn't matter if you press "requires editing" or "looks ok". It is a fine post and shouldn't be reviewed with "unsalvageable", that's all.

Comment: @Machavity sorry but I don't really get what you want to say...

Comment: @Tom do audits work like that? I'm fairly new to it (as you can see from my rep), I thought flagging an "ok" post as "requires editing" would be a failed audit

Comment: @FlorianKoch The problem is the 'Requires Editing" button isn't clear. When you press it in a non-audit, it sends it to `Help and Improvement`, where **queue reviewers** are then asked to edit it to fix it (the button seems to indicate that the OP will be asked to edit it, which is not the case). It's so unclear that I'm not sure how you could fail any Triage audit by pressing it.

Comment: @Machavity oh ok, I get it. But I can tell from experience that it's possible to fail an audit with "Requires Editing": if the audit says iot's unsalvagable

Comment: You're not flagging it. "Requires Editing" just says that this post is fine and a community member can polish it a bit (adding a missing tag, improve grammar/formatting or stuff like this). I wouldn't consider that decision as a misstep like voting "Requires Editing" on an unsalvageable post. (but that is just my guess, I can't tell if that rule is like I wrote here. I might be wrong).

Comment: @Tom sorry, word choice. Of course I didn't mean flagging it in the sense of a real flag, I just meant I press the "Require Editing" Button

Comment: @Machavity  `It's so unclear that I'm not sure how you could fail any Triage audit by pressing it.`  Well you *should* fail an audit if you say that a post that doesn't need editing, needs editing, or if you say that a post that's unsalvageable should be edited.  Sadly this has been broken literally since the queue has been in beta, and SE has known about these problems since before the queues were even finished, and yet we're still here.

Comment: @Servy While I agree that's how it *should* work, it's not how it's used. I think RE should mean `Mostly OK` (and this audit indicates that). The way the description is written (and is *actively used in practice*), however, it can also mean `Mostly Bad`, which almost always overlaps with `Unsalvageable`. Since SO refuses to clarify it so people stop using it as the latter, it defies logic that we should have audits that penalize people for using the button in a way SO implicitly condones.

Comment: @Machavity I'd **much** rather have people fail an audit for following bad advice they're being given, and learn that that advice is bad, than to have people be actively encouraged to perform harmful actions, and reinforce that those harmful actions are what they should be doing.  I can't imagine how making the queues actively harmful is less of a problem then reviewers being upset at finding out SE's instructions are just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all review queues, hitting the button that says the post needs no additional improvement (Looks OK, No action needed, Leave open, or Reopen depending on the queue), in terms of audits, always works exactly the same as the button that says the post needs additional improvement (Edit, Edit and reopen, or Requires editing depending on the queue). The reason for this is that, while the post may be good, it can almost always can be made better. There's no reason to penalize the reviewer for improving an already-good post.

It's the same in Triage. It's not all that uncommon for a question in serious need of improvement to gather some upvotes and answers. It's not fair to penalize the reviewer for saying that an already-good post still needs improvement.

In the specific case you mentioned, the post was good as-is and did not need improvement. However, I still sometimes come across audit questions that are *okay* as-is, but could greatly improve from extensive editing. Sadly, the system just isn't smart enough to know the difference between these, so it passes known-good audits if either "Looks OK" or "Requires Editing" are chosen.

It's also worth noting that spamming the "Requires Editing" button will still fail known-bad audits, which are only passed if "Unsalvageable" is chosen. So this is not another loophole for robo-reviewers to use.