# Very Low Quality flag disputed

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-flags

I am aware that there are several threads here regarding low quality posts. I'd like to understand why my flag was disputed on this question:

[In macOs 10.13.2, /usr/local must be writable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250491/in-macos-10-13-2-usr-local-must-be-writable)

It is too vague, does not have enough information to give an answer and ultimately has nothing to do with programming. It also qualifies for the "This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed." description. I sincerely do not understand what would qualify as Very Low Quality if not a question like this. Could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: personally, i would've done too broad

Comment: Sounds like a usable alternative. But shouldn't moderators/reviewers be able to actually *understand* what is meant and regardless of slight differences in categorization?

Comment: Looks like it went through [triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18519306) with 4 reviewers deciding that *"this question could be good, but requires some time and attention of editors"*. Is it possible that that resultet in the flag being disputed? (Disputed is, by the way, not the same as declined).

Comment: Because VLQ is a flag for moderator, we (mortal community users) should just close these posts. In general don't use that flag not even on answer, nobody on SO (including mods) knows what it actually means. On questions flag to close (users will maybe handle it) or flag as spam/abusive (emergency call for mod) if it is that, On answers flag as NAA (review queue) or spam/abusive (emergency call to mod).

Comment: Here is what the VLQ flag does [What exactly does a VLQ flag do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181796/320339), baah, meeh not very useful and if mod see it on a question that only should be closed and not insta-deleted they will decline.

Comment: Thanks for the link. What I can gather from the information is that the flag is essentially useless and not defined in a way that would make it useful. I may very well be completely wrong in this assessment but it's the extent of what I understand. Should I just ignore the option in the future? I have to say that the more I participate in flagging and voting, the more confusing it gets, to a point that I begin to lose motivation to continue and just become a consumer of information instead of taking part in the so-called community.

Comment: @herrbischoff don't despair, certain stuff yes it is useless (like flagging VLQ a question that should be closed and probably we don't even have enough community users that will close it), but flagging non answers "Thank you mate!", "I have another question" or spam is **not**, they will get deleted within a day. Regarding the VLQ flag it has totally lost it's meaning over time (meta discussions), so yeah I would suggest to not use it.

Comment: There is tons of meta discussions about flagging, how SO works etc and yes it is complex and switch over-time, but to tell the truth for me that's why SO is interesting, community change how stuff should be handled etc. For example should a post containing only "AASDFDLJKSAD" be flagged as spam, not an answer or abusive?? or maybe just be deleted by >20K users?. Use meta and search you will find the answer and if you are stuck join a chat room and ask.

Comment: if you like a crash course in flagging, 500 posts and comments to review per day join us in this [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) there are lots of people that can explain how to flag stuff.

Comment: I recommend never to flag questions as very low quality, and to flag them as should be closed instead. Once I flagged a low quality question as very low quality and my flag was declined, but then the question was closed.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your flag was disputed as [a result of triage reviewers voting that it "Requires Editing"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18519306).

This is most likely due to [the ongoing confusion about what "Requires Editing" means](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319128/triage-review-queue-inconsistent-guidelines-for-requires-editing) in that queue. It's supposed to mean that edits by the community could fix the question, thus sending it to the Help and Improvement queue. Unfortunately, it's often used to indicate something that the poster would need to edit to make sense, thus causing good flags to be disputed and poor posts to be sent to the Help and Improvement queue.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I have always understood the button as "requires cleanup or restructuring". However, this should be made a lot clearer. From the sheer amount of bad questions I come across and now even incorrect categorization, there really should be drastic changes in making fundamental mechanics mandatory to understand for all participants.

Comment: Do you think that the VLQ flag still should be used? or is it better that users stay away from it?. I have a distinct feeling that it has lost meaning on SO and is mostly creating confusion.

Comment: @PetterFriberg - I've laid out some of my thoughts on this here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340873/19679

Comment: Thanks very nice I had not seen that post

Comment: I always thought that "Requires editing" meant that the OP needed to improve their post ... how many times have I improperly flagged a post !

Comment: Because of this answer now I know what the "Requires Editing" really mean.  It has helped me improve my queue tasks.

Comment: "Requires editing" should be renamed to "I can fix this!"